# Creating a grid type 3D data array from data points

Tags: python, data, numpy

I have a 3 data column $(X, Y, Z)$ ranges from $(min, max)$. For example,

$X = (0, 5)$, $Y=(0, 3)$, $Z=(0, 2)$. By using them I need to create a numpy array in the form of

$[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0)...]$

So in total there will be $6 \times 4 \times 3 = 72$ data points.

Is there a simple command to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get a possible combinations of x, y, and z and then convert to resulting list to a `numpy` array:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

x = range(0, 5 + 1)
y = range(0, 3 + 1)
z = range(0, 2 + 1)

np.array(list(itertools.product(x, y, z)))
```